# Approximating the computation of arctan via a boundary value problem

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

Suppose

$$
f(x) = \arctan(x)
$$

We can write

$$
f^{(2)}(x) = 2x\left( f^{(1)}(x) \right)^2
$$

Subject to some boundary condition $f(a) = c, f(b) = d$.
I'm not an expert in this boundary value problems, but I'd like to know what kind of iteration I can use to solve such kind of problem.

I've tried to look at the "shooting method" (I think that's how it's called) but I can't use it because it applies only to linear problems.

Is there anything else I can use?

Even a reference is fine, I'd prefer something which is easy to implement, so I can test it quickly.

Comment: Can you cite the place where it states that the shooting method only applies to linear problems? IMO in linear problems the application of the shooting method is so trivial that it almost does not deserve the name.

Comment: Can you show me the iteration then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method, Now that I read better it is stated specifically for linear problems.

Comment: The general explanation on the WP page is for general second order ODE and the example at the end is non-linear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to transform the boundary condition into initial conditions in my case.

Answer (score 1):

user8469759: *"I'm not sure I understand how to transform the boundary condition into initial conditions in my case."*

Exactly that is the purpose of the shooting method, to transform the second boundary condition into a slope at the first boundary. That is to solve the inverse problem to the equation $\phi(v)=d$ where $\phi(v)=f(b)$ for the solution $f$ to the initial value problem with $f(a)=c$, $f'(a)=v$.

If there were a known inverse function to $\phi$ there would be no problem to solve with the shooting method or any other. In general $\phi$ is a smooth non-linear function, and neither the existence nor the uniqueness of a solution to $\phi(v)=d$ are guaranteed.

As always with non-linear root finders you need some, most likely heuristic, globalization strategy to try a sufficient number of initial slopes to get a global picture of where to look for the correct solution. This can be as simple as picking two random slopes $v_1,v_2$ to start the secant method for $\phi$.

```
def shoot(x0,y0,xf,yf, eps):
    def derivs(y,x): return [ y[1], 2*x*min(1e10,y[1]**2) ]
    def fb(v0): return odeint(derivs, [y0, v0], [x0, xf], atol=0.01*eps, rtol=0.1*eps)[-1,0]

    v = (yf-y0)/(xf-x0)
    v1 = 0.735*v; fb1 = fb(v1)-yf;
    v2 = 1.234*v; fb2 = fb(v2)-yf;
    while abs(v2-v1)>eps*(1+abs(v2)):
        v3 = v2-fb2*(v2-v1)/(fb2-fb1);
        v1, fb1, v2, fb2 = v2, fb2, v3, fb(v3)-yf
        print "v=%.13f fb(v)=%.13g"%(v2,fb2)
    return v2

x0=0; y0=0; xf=1; yf=0.8; eps=1e-9
v0 = shoot(x0, y0, xf, yf, eps)
A = (v0/(1+v0*x0**2))**0.5
print "exact solution with computed parameters: f(xf)=%.13f"%(A*m.atanh(A*xf))
```

with the result

```
v=0.5925363255730 fb(v)=-0.01503501130161
v=0.5954088487471 fb(v)=-0.00959298035706
v=0.6004724102490 fb(v)=7.126956548664e-05
v=0.6004350687242 fb(v)=-3.369897517702e-07
v=0.6004352444583 fb(v)=-1.181577058418e-11
v=0.6004352444645 fb(v)=1.387778780781e-14
exact solution with computed parameters: f(xf)=0.7999999986750
```

The exact solution is: 
\begin{align}
v'=2xv^2
&\implies 
1/v_0-1/v(x)=x^2-x_0^2
\\
f'=v=\dfrac1{1/v_0+x_0^2-x^2}
&\implies 
f(x)=A\cdot \operatorname{Artanh}(Ax)
\text{ where } 
A=\sqrt{\frac{v_0}{1+v_0x_0^2}}
\end{align}
so that with the computed values $A=1/\sqrt{x_0^2+1/v_0}=\sqrt{v_0}=\sqrt{0.6004352444645}=0.77487756740305624$ and indeed
$$
A\cdot{\rm Artanh}(A\cdot 1)=0.79999999867501892
$$
gives the second boundary condition within the error level.

You might have remarked that the solution is not the arcus tangent, as that has the differential equation $f''=-2xf'^2$.